# Laravel component access data from component declaration

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-7

I'm using regular [Laravel Component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-components)

I know we can acccess data within the component itself, but can we do the same with the declaration ?

Let's take the following declared component :

```
<x-code :show="$canBeShow"></x-code>
```

I'm getting variable `$canBeShow undefined`

Could it be possible this variable to be accessible here, knowing it is declared as public variable and in the constructor in the corresponding class ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting variable undefined, because it is on the component level and not on the declaration (I think)